# Play Dash or .mpd videos react-native(IOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, mpeg-dash, react-native-video

I am working on an app which has a media server and this media server provide me the URL's of different video files and these videos are in `dash` format or `.mpd` format. I go through react-native-video and it has `exo-player` on `android` which already have the support of `dash`,
I have tested `exo-player` on `andriod` and it works but on the other hand, it uses `AVPlayer` for `IOS` which don't have any support of dash.
I spent some time finding some solution on the IOS side which could also support React-Native `android` and `IOS` but didn't find a proper way, Found two solutions but not works for both.

dash.js - https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki

Google Shaka Player - https://github.com/google/shaka-player

`dash.js` have only support for `web` and `shaka-player` have some embedded solution available on `IOS` and which I have to bridge and then I can use.

I am looking for some quick workaround on react-native, Is there any player available that can play `dash` on both platforms or any other workaround that can work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key reason you may not see as much attention for DASH players in iOS as you expect is that current apple iOS rules require you to use HLS on iOS devices for any video over 10 minutes, assuming your app is available on mobile networks which is nearly always the case:

> 2.5.7 Video streaming content over a cellular network longer than 10 minutes must use HTTP Live Streaming and include a baseline 192 kbps HTTP Live stream.

(https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

This is a key reason most video streams at this time are available in both HLS and DASH streams.

Note that the CMAF format promises to eventually allow you only store and server single copy of your content by effectively having the segmented video streams be the same with different HLS and DASH 'index' or 'manifest' files to refer to them. Because of some differences in the way encryption has been done in the past, and the time it will take for all devices and players to support the new format and new agreed encryption support, in practice nearly all encrypted streams will be both HLS and DASH for some time.

(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/about_the_common_media_application_format_with_http_live_streaming)